# Toggle Caps Lock key on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos

We use `Scroll Lock` (`VK_SCROLL`) for debugging on Windows by raising an exception when the key is pressed. This can be detected using:

```
LONG key_state = GetKeyState(VK_SCROLL);
return (key_state & 0x01) != 0;
```

On Mac, `Scroll Lock` is not available so we check for `Caps Lock` as follows:

```
CGEventFlags mod = CGEventSourceFlagsState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
if ( mod & kCGEventFlagMaskAlphaShift )
    return true;

return false;
```

On startup, we need to ensure `Scroll Lock` or `Caps Lock` is definitely off. On Windows, I can toggle `VK_SCROLL` off as follows:

```
s_set_key_state(VK_SCROLL, FALSE);
extern void s_set_key_state(BYTE key, BOOL bState)
{
    // Toggle an extended key (eg. VK_NUMLOCK or VK_SCROLL)
    BYTE keyState[256];
    GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState);
    if ((bState && !(keyState[key] & 1)) ||
        (!bState && (keyState[key] & 1)))
    {
        // Toggle the key by simulating a key press, then key release
        keybd_event(key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
        keybd_event(key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}
```

How to toggle Caps Lock off on MacOS or Linux? The OS can be detected at compile-time, so we can changed `VK_SCROLL` for the MacOS equivalent for `Caps Lock`.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to break in your debugger, not create a chain of hacks surrounding OS-owned keyboard keys...

Comment: This is not my codebase, so that comment isn't helpful. Our situation seems a reasonable use case for this type of functionality, and something I had not see before. Finding exactly **where** an event happens is next to impossible with this hodgepodge of old C and C++ code. If it were easy to find where to put the breakpoint, you'd just do that. But with strategically-placed checks for `Scroll Lock` or `Caps Lock`, in DEBUG mode only, we can break close(ish) to where the event occurs and use the `Call Stack` to get even closer.